# SQLite on AppDelegate required?

Tags: sqlite, uiapplicationdelegate

Is it always required that SQLITE be declared on AppDelegate ? What if I want the SQL query to be used later in the views ? or I'm planning to switch to different DBs dynamically. Was looking on possibility of creating a separate new class to handle SQLITE (such as SQLiteManager) to manage all SQLite related operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, its totally not necessary to declare your SQLite stuff in `AppDelegate` unless you need it at the very start of the app.

I've got an app on the store which works with SQLite in the same manner you said, via a separate 'SQLiteManager' class which has all the SQLite declarations, DB logins, data handling, query building etc. And whenever I need DB access in my app, I simply import this class and make use of it.

Comment: Thanks. This did help. If not most, all of the tutorials I see pertaining to SQLITE always declare it on AppDelegate, thus thought that Apple recommends it to be declared there.